# When installing python-language-server in Arch, how do I ensure that it uses YAPF for code formatting?

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, python

The package `python-language-server` (Python LSP support) is a new optional dependency for Kate editor in Arch Linux.

Here's some background on why that might be interesting:

[Langserver.org](https://langserver.org/)

> **Why LSP?** LSP creates the opportunity to reduce the m-times-n complexity problem of providing a high level of support for any programming language in any editor, IDE, or client endpoint to a simpler m-plus-n problem.

I decided I want to try it out. So I checked here for more info:

[palantir/python-language-server: An implementation of the Language Server Protocol for Python](https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server)

I would like to use [YAPF](https://github.com/google/yapf), so I took note of this info:

> Optional providers can be installed using the extras syntax. To install YAPF formatting for example:

```
pip install 'python-language-server[yapf]'
```

I want to install it using the Arch repos instead of pip. **My question is, how would I achieve the same result when installing 'python-language-server' from the Arch repos?** Would this be equivalent?

```
pacman -Syu python-language-server yapf
```

Optional background: why I want to use YAPF:

> Most of the current formatters for Python --- e.g., autopep8, and pep8ify --- are made to remove lint errors from code. This has some obvious limitations. For instance, code that conforms to the PEP 8 guidelines may not be reformatted. But it doesn't mean that the code looks good.
>
> YAPF takes a different approach. It's based off of 'clang-format', developed by Daniel Jasper. In essence, the algorithm takes the code and reformats it to the best formatting that conforms to the style guide, even if the original code didn't violate the style guide. The idea is also similar to the 'gofmt' tool for the Go programming language: end all holy wars about formatting - if the whole codebase of a project is simply piped through YAPF whenever modifications are made, the style remains consistent throughout the project and there's no point arguing about style in every code review.
>
> The ultimate goal is that the code YAPF produces is as good as the code that a programmer would write if they were following the style guide. It takes away some of the drudgery of maintaining your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

`pacman -S python-language-server yapf` would achieve the same result as `pip install 'python-language-server[yapf]'`. You can even prove this by installing with pacman and then try the `pip` command and it will tell you Requirement already satisfied.

```bsh
$ pip install 'python-language-server[yapf]'
Requirement already satisfied: python-language-server[yapf] in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.31.7)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi<0.16,>=0.14.1 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-language-server[yapf]) (0.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-jsonrpc-server>=0.3.2 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-language-server[yapf]) (0.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pluggy in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-language-server[yapf]) (0.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ujson<=1.35 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-language-server[yapf]) (1.35)
Requirement already satisfied: yapf in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-language-server[yapf]) (0.29.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parso>=0.5.0 in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from jedi<0.16,>=0.14.1->python-language-server[yapf]) (0.6.1)
```